# It is possible to use OpenMP on these fortran loops?

Tags: fortran, openmp, nested-loops, do-loops

Here is my problem: I have a fortran code with a certain amount of nested loops and I would like to know if it's possible to use OpenMP to parallelize them?

Here is the fortran code:

```
  ia = 0
  do i=1,nO
    do a=nO+1,N
      ia = ia + 1

      jb = 0
      do j=1,nO
        do b=nO+1,N
          jb = jb + 1

          chi = 0d0
          do kc=1,nS
            eps = B(kc)**2 + eta**2
            chi = chi + A(i,j,kc)*A(a,b,kc)*B(kc)/eps
          enddo

          C(ia,jb) = C(ia,jb) + D(i,b,j,a) - 4d0*chi

        enddo
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
```

Where nS = nO*(N-nO). For the dimensions of the arrays: B(nS), A(N,N,nS), C(nS,nS), D(N,N,N,N) . An example for the different integers: nO=88, N=240, nS=13376. Maybe it is worth mentioning that I run it on the cluster of my lab and not my laptop.

I know nothing about OpenMP and I tried to do it myself with examples that I found but I did not succeed. I have seen many different commands with OpenMP like `PRIVATE`, `SHARED`, `REDUCTION` and I tried to use them without success.

Comment: Your code is quite incomplete. You do not show the declarations of your variables and arrays and you do not show the initial value of `jb`. I tried to answer despite these limitations, but it is really much better to show more code in your questions. See the related note in my answer.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава yes sorry for that. You are right, `jb` is initialized to 0 just after the `ia = ia+1` part. All tables are double precision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. But it will also be good to rewrite the code somewhat. Notice that you can always compute the value of `ia` from the known values of `i` and `a`. There is no need to do the `ia = ia + 1` additions. Similarly, you can always compute `jb` from `j` and `b`.

```
  do i=1,nO
    do a=nO+1,N
      do j=1,nO
        do b=nO+1,N        
          ia = (a-n0) + (i-1)*(N-n0)
          jb = (b-n0) + (j-1)*(N-n0)

          chi = 0d0
          do kc=1,nS
            eps = B(kc)**2 + eta**2
            chi = chi + A(i,j,kc)*A(a,b,kc)*B(kc)/eps
          enddo

          C(ia,jb) = C(ia,jb) + D(i,b,j,a) - 4d0*chi

        enddo
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
```

---

As Ian Bush reminded me in the comment, the memory access pattern is bad. In Fortran, the memory order of the storage of array elements is column-major. That means that the first index should be in the innermost loop and the last index in the outermost loop for best efficiency. That can be achieved by declaring your arrays transposed or by restructuring the loop nests - which may not always be possible.

In the code above you can switch the order of the `i,j,a,b` loops without any change to the logic

```
  do j=1,nO
    do b=nO+1,N     
      do i=1,nO
        do a=nO+1,N
```

but it would help even more if the `kc` index was the first one.

If re-declaring your arrays - this may have a large impact on the run time of your program. This also concerns other parts of you whole program. You have to take the whole program into account.

---

After that you can apply OpenMP.

I would start with a simple:

```
!$omp parallel do default(private) shared(A,B,C,D,n0,N,nS)
```

Later, if it runs correctly, you try different `schedule` to find out what is faster and possibly also try `collapse(4)`.

Comment: No comment on the memory access pattern? I think I'd fix that before I thought about omp

Comment: @IanBush I did not really look at that at all. I even had to add the D array into the list in an edit after i find out there is alsothis one.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава thanks for your answer! Is there any error in your definitions of `ia` and `jb` using the value of `i`, `a`, `j` and `b`? `ia` should start at 1 but it's not the case with your solution.

Comment: @User3000 Yes, a small one.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I tried your answer without OpenMP and it's working, thanks again! But I have a problem when I'm trying to use OpenMP. I have tried to use your command but I have an unexpected assignement statement error because of `ia=0`. I also tried to put the command after `ia=0` but the result is wrong.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава about your comment on the `kc` sum, it doesn't look easy to put it as the first loop...

Comment: @User3000 You would have to declare your arrays in a different order.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I put it after `ia=0` and the result is wrong

Comment: The `ia=0` should not be there. You just add `!$omp parallel do default(private) shared(A,B,C,D,n0,N,nS)` right in front of the loop nest. I forgot to add those constants into the `shared` clause. Please go through the code and verify it is all and I did not miss some more. I cannot be expected to avoid such small bugs without being able to test the full code. There is some independent programming and debugging activity expected.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава It's working with OpenMP! Thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience, next time I will put all the code in my question. For the declaration of arrays in a different order I'm not sure to see it... But I will work on it!